# Display notification when file is modified/added/removed

Tags: macos, notifications, applescript

I would like to create an applescript that displays an os X notification when files in a specific folder gets added/modified/removed.

I ran across [this](http://www.cooperative-fruitiere.com/notifications/index_en.html) which is what I want to display, but don't know how to implement it with watching a folder being modified.

Don't know much about applescript, but have some web development experience.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

P

Answer (score 0):

Without coding, the best you can do is to write a launchd config:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>org.test.watch</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                 <string>/script/to/run</string>
                 <string>arg</string>
                 <string>otherArg</string>
        </array>
        <key>WatchPaths</key>
        <array>
                 <string>/dir/to/watch/</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Put it to `~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.test.watch.plist` and load with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.test.watch.plist`.
Every time something happens with files or folders under /dir/to/watch, /script/to/run is invoked.

You may find more information in `man launchd.plist`.

Note that it doesn't allow you to know what actually happened, just that *something* changed. If you need more details, a bit of coding with FSEvents framework is required.